# implementing tabs with fragments instead of TabActivity issue

Tags: android

I have used this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) to implement tabs with fragments instead of TabActivity and it worked greate for some time I have two tabs with ListFragment.
the problem is that suddenly the realTabContent disappeared from the view now I can see TabWidget and change the tab but nothing displayed with no exception and when close the activity with tabs and open again it worked perfectly as expected.
Have any one faced this problem? and what may cause this behaviour?

Comment: Amal, I am facing the same issue. Were you ever able to fix this? If so, how?

Comment: @littleK no I didn't it just appeared one time and never happened again so I couldn't make any further tests, sorry.